# Geofence event enter triggers only once when start the app

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I have followed the android official [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) on geofencing, line by line. Though I think it works, but I have noticed that geofence event is triggered only once on starting the app. Also the exit event is never triggered. Any help or explanation in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Add your actual code to the question, otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I found out that I have set expirationDuration to 10 seconds only. @GeraldSchneider next time I will definitely post my code too.